# aggregation for matching date fields

Tags: elasticsearch

My data type has two different DateTime fields in it.    I'd like to aggregate all the records where the two date fields are the same.

I'm looking at the filter aggregation, but it seems to require knowing a specific value upfront.   This isn't quite the right tool for the job.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need aggregation?do you want to just retrieve records where two dates have same value and also group them if they have same values?

Comment: I wanted to get the records with the matching dates and then try to run a cardinality function so that they are collapsed into counts for occurrences that belong to the same account number.     I fail on the first step of this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) to get records with same value in two date fields. You would need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting).

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "inline": "doc['datefield1'].value == doc['datefield2'].value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After that you can run your aggregations on the records you get.